# Why is "public" not allowed for properties in JPA entities?

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

The [JPA 2.0 specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr317/index.html) says on page 22:

> The instance variables of a class must
>   be private, protected, or package
>   visibility independent of whether
>   field access or property access is
>   used. When property access is used,
>   the property accessor methods must be
>   public or protected.

Why isn't public access allowed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With public fields, there would be no way for proxying to work reliably -- if someone accesses a field directly, then there is no simple way for the persistence framework to intercept that call and (say) initialize the containing object, if it's a proxy.

If field access is not possible, synthetic getter methods can be generated on the proxy object to intercept the method calls and do any required 'behind-the-scenes' work.

Comment: there would be no way for proxying to work reliably << This is not right. (AOP..)

Comment: Agree with Martin K, bytecode enhancement also solves the problem - see other answer

Comment: I should have been more clear, but I did say "no _simple_ way" later on. To a certain extent, the JPA spec is a 'lowest common denominator' between the different frameworks -- requiring frameworks to use AOP, or enhance the _calling_ class (as I gather DataNucleus does) would certainly be excessive for the JPA spec. Other persistence engines are, I guess, welcome to provide functionality BEYOND what JPA specifies, but to require field access interception for JPA spec compliance would be... onerous.

Comment: Possibly more importantly, some frameworks and tools in Java hides the get- and set-part, on top of my mind this holds true for Expression Language as used for example in JSP, JSF and Facelets. If the field is public there is now now way to separate which one the programmer means except long-distance mind-reading.

Answer (score 5):

With DataNucleus as JPA provider you could use public fields, **but** you would then need to mark any classes that access these fields as "persistence aware" (see the DataNucleus docs), so they can be enhanced to cater for this

Answer (score -1):

To be sure that accessor methods are used (like get... set.... is.... ). Thats part of the isolation principle.

Comment: But is there a technical requirement from JPA to enforce this (sometimes only pseudo) encapsulation?

Comment: It's API design. Many implementations deal with lazy proxies etc. Taking care of method access trees and subclasses is a lot easier than handle attribute access.